# replacing the docker desktop to rancher desktop

Tags: docker, visual-studio, rancher-desktop

I need to change my docker desktop to rancher desktop from my project. I'm using windows, I installed the rancher desktop. how is it going to see my project's credentials? I couldn't make it run locally.
any help?